# Java Array Index out of bound exception while storing in to 2D array

Tags: java

My Excel contains values like this.

1. Row 1: Test Case Name
2. Row 2: Header Parameter Values
3. Row 3: Parameters for IE
4. Row 4: Parameters for Chrome
5. Row 5: Parameater for Firefox..

I am extracting each row values and store it in LinkedHashMap. I am creating one 2D array and storing this linkedHashmap in to that 2D array..

It is returning Index Out of Bound exception. Can any one correct to store table values in to StoreAllArray

```
package com.xchanging.selenium.utility;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ReadExcel {

    public static LinkedHashMap<String, String> getData(String sheetName,
            String testCaseName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Entry Point");
        XSSFWorkbook sourceBook = new XSSFWorkbook("./TestCases.xlsx");
        XSSFSheet sourceSheet = sourceBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        int testCaseStartRow = 0;
        while (!sourceSheet.getRow(testCaseStartRow).getCell(0)
                .getRichStringCellValue().toString().equals(testCaseName)) {
            testCaseStartRow++;
        }
        System.out.println("testCaseStartingRow: " + testCaseStartRow);

        int testCaseStartColumn = 0;
        int headerRow = testCaseStartRow + 1;
        int keyRow = headerRow + 1;

        while (sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(testCaseStartColumn) != null) {
            testCaseStartColumn++;
        }
        int lastColumn = testCaseStartColumn - 1;
        // int parameters = lastColumn + 1;
        int numberofRows = keyRow;
        System.out.println("Keys Start Row" + keyRow);
        while (!sourceSheet.getRow(numberofRows).getCell(0).toString()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("End")) {
            System.out.println(sourceSheet.getRow(numberofRows).getCell(0));
            numberofRows++;
        }
        System.out.println("numberofRows " + numberofRows);
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> table = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        // Object[][] testData = new Object[0][lastColumn];
        Object[][] storeAllArray = new Object[0][3];
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = keyRow; i < numberofRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= lastColumn; j++) {
                int cellType = sourceSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).getCellType();
                if (cellType == 0) {
                    String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                            .toString();
                    String value = Double.toString(sourceSheet.getRow(i)
                            .getCell(j).getNumericCellValue());
                    table.put(key, value);
                } else if (cellType == 1) {
                    String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                            .toString();
                    String value = sourceSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j).toString();
                    table.put(key, value);

                } else if (cellType == 2) {
                    String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                            .toString();
                    String value = sourceSheet.getRow(i).getCell(j)
                            .getRawValue().toString();
                    table.put(key, value);

                } else if (cellType == 4) {
                    String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                            .toString();
                    String value = Boolean.toString(sourceSheet.getRow(i)
                            .getCell(j).getBooleanCellValue());
                    table.put(key, value);

                } else {
                    String key = sourceSheet.getRow(headerRow).getCell(j)
                            .toString();
                    String value = "";
                    table.put(key, value);
                }

            }
            storeAllArray[0][count] = table;
            count++;
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at
>   com.xchanging.selenium.utility.ReadExcel.getData(ReadExcel.java:81)
>     at
>   com.xchanging.selenium.utility.DataProviderConvertor.convertData(DataProviderConvertor.java:11)
>     at
>   com.xchanging.selenium.testcases.SanitySuite.main(SanitySuite.java:11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object[][] storeAllArray = new Object[0][3];` is an array with `0` rows. You can't put anything in it, which is why `storeAllArray[0][count]` fails.

Change it to :

```
Object[][] storeAllArray = new Object[1][3];
```

Assuming one row is enough and `count` never goes beyond 2. Of course, if there's only one row, you don't need a 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayIndexOutofBondsException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Trycatch2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {10,20,30};
        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter int index[0-2]");
        try
        {
            int index = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("element="+a[index]);
        }
        catch(ArrayIndexOutofBondsException e)
        {
            System.out.println("invalid int index using 0 as default index");
            System.out.println("elements="+a[0]);
        }
        System.out.println("bye");
        sc.close();
    }
}

    enter code here


show error
```